# MYSQL does not start anymore after trying to reset root password

Tags: mysql, password

I have an hard time figuring what to do to get mysql service working well again, any help would be more then appreciated.

I did tried to reset password with this method:

Stop the Service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Start MySQL without a password

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Connect to MySQL

```
mysql -uroot
```

Set a new MySQL root password

```
mysql>  use mysql;

mysql>  update user set authentication_string=password('yourNewPwd') `where user='root';`

mysql>  flush privileges;

mysql>  quit
```

Re-start mysql service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Now, you can login with your updated password

```
mysql -u root -p
```

[tutorial found:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007128/reset-root-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-x)

And I got this result when trying to check mysql status:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2019-04-29 12:19:37 EDT; 2min 8s ago
  Process: 10761 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/m
  Process: 10752 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exi
 Main PID: 1038 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Comment: what version of ubuntu? the command you use is ... old. it nowadays is `sudo service mysql stop|start|restart` Your last part is new (ie. systemd). I see nothing wrong with what you did. do you have a mysql log in /var/log? If you do there will be a notice there

Comment: I did the stop|start|restart to, I am under ubuntu 18.04. Yes I found the log file and it contain alot.

Answer (score 0):

```
service stop mysql
cd /var/lib/mysql
rm ib_logfile*
service start mysql
```

Comment: Before removing a file best practise is to make a backup.